# Using datestr(now) with save

Tags: matlab

The code is:

```
filename = sprintf('michael%s.bat',datestr(now));
...

save (filename,vec)
```

`vec` is a vector

I'm getting this error:

```
Error using save
Argument must contain a string.

Error in sumfnc (line 13)
save (filename,vec)
```

I'm unsure on how `filename` is not a string.

Comment: See the function form of save [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)

Comment: I assume you mean `'michael%s.mat'`, not `'michael%s.bat'`, or are you really writing to a .bat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not `filename`, it is `vec`.  With the functional usage of [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), you need to do:

```
save(filename,'vec')
```

However, since `filename` will contain a space, you will also need to modify `filename`.  Try:

```
save(strrep(filename,' ','_'),'vec')
```

to replace spaces with `_`.